# Eclipse very slow when deleting or creating class

Tags: eclipse

When I'm creating a class or deleting a class in the Package Explorer, Eclipse could take up to 10 minutes before completing the task and sometime it never complete. To continue working, I need to kill Eclipse.

Is there someone who know how to fix it ?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7 64.

Comment: try netbeans. still written in java, but a LOT better performance than eclipse.

Comment: Try Linux and Eclipse...eclipse is flying!

Comment: This is strange. Might be related to a plugin or some network drives or something, but I am just guessing. Your could try to update java to the latest version, get a clean eclipse with no plugins (other than basic java stuff), use a clean workspace and retry

Comment: Try:

 1) Checking if it is the same with a small project in a fresh workspace.
 2) Checking if it is the same with a small project in the same workspace.
 3) Disabling your antivirus.
 4) Disabling Project -> Build automatically.

Based on the results I can give advice on how to solve it.

Comment: I have been using eclipse for around 7 years on different OSs and this is the first time for me face such a case, so there is no need to suggest a different IDE altogether !

Comment: I also had the problem and the reason was this bug here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354842